# Processing JSON files containing lists of integers using jq

Tags: json, list, jq

I'm currently looking into using `jq` to process JSON files that contain lists of integers, such as the example below —

```
[
  {
    "box_id": 1,
    "number_items": [
      4,
      6,
      7,
      5
    ]
  },
  {
    "box_id": 3,
    "number_items": [
      15,
      null,
      15,
      9
    ]
  },
  {
    "box_id": 6,
    "number_items": [
      2,
      4,
      0,
      1
    ]
  }
]
```

First, I'm trying to get the maximum for each `box_id`. Just getting the maximum values is relatively straightforward with e.g. `jq '.[].number_items | max`, which returns

```
7
15
4
```

However, I would like to store this into a new JSON file, like so —

```
[
  {
    "box_id": 1,
    "max_items": 7
  },
  {
    "box_id": 3,
    "max_items": 15
  },
  {
    "box_id": 6,
    "max_items": 4
  }
]
```

The other part is somewhat more involved — how to find the sum of absolute differences of consecutive entries in the lists for each `box_id`? As example, consider `[4,6,7,5]`, which corresponds to differences `[6-4=2, 7-6=1, 5-7=-2]` = `[2,1,-2]`. The sum of absolute values of that one is `2+1+2` = `5`. Note that the lists can contain `null` values. These entries should be removed, so that in the case of `[15,null,15,9]` we get `[15,15,9]` which corresponds to differences `[0,-6]` and to absolute sum `6`.

Comment: show the final result including *absolute values*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a tiny bit of familiarity with jq, the first problem is trivial, so I won't say more than give a solution:

```
map( {box_id, max_items: (.number_items | max) } )
```

The requirements for the second problem are a bit unclear, but you can easily tweak the following to meet your needs.  First, a helper function,  `differences`:

```
# Input: an array
# Output: a non-empty stream of non-negative integers
def differences:
  def abs: if . < 0 then - . else . end;
  map( select(. != null) )
  | if length == 0 then 0
    elif length == 1 then (.[0]|abs)
    else range(1;length) as $i | ( .[$i] - .[$i - 1] ) | abs end;
```

You could then use this like so:

```
map( {box_id, sumAD: ( [.number_items | differences] | add) } )
```

However it would be better (from a memory usage standpoint) to take advantage of the fact that `differences` emits a stream:

```
def sigma(s): reduce s as $x (0; . + $x);
map( {box_id, sumAD: ( sigma(.number_items | differences) ) } )
```